# How to change kubectl logs timestamp timezone

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

The timezone did not meet my expectations When i use `kubectl logs <mypod> --timestamps` to get the pod log.

current output:

```bash
2022-06-15T07:31:41.826543867Z 2022/06/15 15:31:41 [info] Start grpc server listen 58212 port.
2022-06-15T07:31:41.826568525Z 2022/06/15 15:31:41 [info] Start http server listen 10000 port.
```

expected output:

```bash
2022-06-15T15:31:41+0800 2022/06/15 15:31:41 [info] Start grpc server listen 58212 port.
2022-06-15T15:31:41+0800 2022/06/15 15:31:41 [info] Start http server listen 10000 port.
```

What should I set up to achieve this output?

Comment: Note that the `Z` at the end of the timestamp denotes [Coordinated Universal Time](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Are you sure that your times are 15:31:41 UTC?

Comment: sry, I forgot to modify the Z in the back, I mainly express what I expect

Comment: The main point I want to express is, is there a way to format the timestamp into the time zone I want

Comment: You can still edit your question and remove the `Z`, if it is about displaying the logs in a specified timezone. If I understand correctly, you want to change `07:31:41Z` to `15:31:41+0800`, right?

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to say, thanks for the reminder, I forgot I could edit it, thanks !

Comment: with only `kubectl` there is no native flag to do that. you would have to use 2nd tool to parse the time format if its worth doing it.

Answer (score 3):

`kubectl` does not support this directly at the time of writing this and it tricky to do this in a portable way. On Linux something like this would work:

```
kubectl logs --timestamps mypod | while read timestamp line; do \
  echo "$(env TZ="EST" date -d "$timestamp" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N%:z') $line"; done
```

You will get an output like this:

```
2022-06-08T14:13:41.847615539-05:00 INFO [06-08|19:13:41.847] Starting Geth on Ethereum mainnet...
```

Comment: This method is great, but I prefer kubectl to support it natively (but it seems that it does not work now)